# Good practice to hold a file or channel in a class

Tags: file, logging, chapel

In the following code, I am trying to make a class which can write something to a log file when asked via a method. Here, I am wondering if this is an idiomatic way for this purpose, or possibly is there a more recommended way, e.g., hold a separate field of `file` type (for some reason)? In other words, is it pratically no problem even if I hold only a `channel` type?

```
class Myclass {
    var logfile: channel;

    proc init() {
        writeln( "creating log.out" );
        logfile = openwriter( "log.out" );
    }
    proc log( x ) {
        logfile.writeln( x );
    }
}

proc main() {
    var a = new borrowed Myclass();
    a.log( 10 );
    a.log( "orange" );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you're doing here is reasonable.  The distinction between files and channels in Chapel is primarily made in support of the language's parallel computing theme, in order to support having multiple tasks access a single logical file simultaneously using distinct channels (views into the file, essentially).  In a case like yours, there is a file underlying the channel you've created, but there's no need to explicitly store it if you have no need to interact further with it.

So I believe there is no practical problem to simply storing a channel as you have here.

Comment: Thanks very much! Although Chapel has the concept of "channel", it has no counterpart in other languages I used, so I was not sure if it might cause some issues later. If no problem, I will directly use channels in the above case.

Comment: Channels are particularly useful if, say, you have a large binary file and you want multiple tasks to read from it simultaneously.  You can open the file, establish a channel to it per task, have each task seek their channel to the appropriate offset in the file for their chunk of data and read simultaneously.