# A field of "channel" type gives error "Cannot default-initialize a variable with generic type"

Tags: file, generics, chapel

In this code, I am creating a class that contains a channel that may be opened upon request when initialized. To do so, I am passing a flag to indicate whether a channel is opened or not (together with its file name).

```
class Myclass
{
    var writeflag : bool;
    var output : channel;

    proc init( writeflag = false, filename = "" )
    {
        this.writeflag = writeflag;
        if writeflag {                   // (1)
            assert( filename != "" );
            this.output = openwriter( filename );
        }                                // (2)
    }
}

proc main()
{
    var a = new owned Myclass( writeflag = true,
                               filename = "test.out" );
    a.output.writeln( 123 );
}
```

However, the compiler rejects the above code with the message:

> myclass.chpl:6: error: Cannot default-initialize a variable with generic type
>   myclass.chpl:6: note: 'not-fully-instantiated' has generic type 'channel'

On the other hand, if I comment out (1) and (2), the code works as expected and creates "test.out". I guess the problem is related to the generic nature of `channel` (according to the error message), but not very sure how to write such a code appropriately...

Comment: [`channel.isclosed()`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.channel.isclosed) might be helpful for your application, in case you weren't aware of it.

Comment: You don't get the error when the if statement is commented out because the lack of an else branch is what is triggering the error message.  Basically, the Chapel compiler knows the type for output when you assign to it, but if the if statement isn't triggered, it doesn't know what default value to give it (hence bencray's recommendation).

Comment: I see... I think it explains the behavior of the above code, and why such an error did not occur in my [previous code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54913042/3501546). Thanks very much :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess the problem is related to the generic nature of channel (according to the error message), but not very sure how to write such a code appropriately...

You're on the right track. The [channel record](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.channel) has some param fields which must be provided at compile-time. You can specify these parameters in the field declaration:

```
var output : channel(writing=true, kind=iokind.dynamic, locking=false);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I've confirmed that the code now works. And I have one minor question...  Is "locking=false" better than "true" in the above particular case? (Here, I will not write from within a parallel region.) Is locking=false possibly more efficient when only serial write is to be performed?

Comment: "locking=false" is indeed more efficient. However, we suggest that you resort to it only in performance-critical code. Also, you'd need to pass "locking=false" to openwriter() as well.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions in the answer and comment, I have modified my code as follows. Because the concrete type is a bit long to remember, I have created a type alias and used it in the class specification (here with `locking=true` for generality, please see [docs](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/standard/IO.html#IO.openwriter)).

```
// utils.chpl
type Writer = channel( true,  iokind.dynamic, true );
type Reader = channel( false, iokind.dynamic, true );    

// test.chpl
use utils only Writer;

class Myclass
{
    var writeflag : bool;
    var output : Writer;

    // ... the remaining is the same
}
```